# Creating a QFile with non-unicode name

Tags: c++, encoding, qt4

I have a string in KOI8-R encoding, it's passed as argv, so initially it's a char* object. Using this deprecated encoding can't be helped at this point, unfortunately. The system locale is KOI8-R, and the source code is in this encoding too.

The string is a path to a file where some of the directories have names in KOI8-R. I need to open the file to write using QFile. However, open() always returns false no matter what I try.

I need to convert the path to QString to pass it to the constructor of QFile, however, straightforward conversion, QString::fromLocal8Bit() and QFile::decodeName() don't seem to help.

```
char* filename; // This is a KOI8-R string
QFile f(QString::fromLocal8Bit(filename));
// QFile f(QFile::decodeName(filename)) doesn't work too
f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text); // returns false
```

The only way I made it work was with the help of ofstream objects from STL, passing char* to ofstream constructor works fine, however, the use of QFile is much more preferable as the application is in QT.

Comment: Quick question... Are you sure that certain path exists? If you're using QFile, then directory where you want to create file MUST exists

Comment: Also what does errorString() on QFile say?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is somewhere with the encoding. I changed the code to make it create a file with non-unicode name in current directory (the filename is hardcoded), and non-unicode characters just disappear from the name: it was "тест1.txt" in the code and the file that was created was called just "1.txt". In the directory name, the non-unicode part was missing thus making the path non-existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this was to add QApplication initialization (QApplication a(argc, argv);) BEFORE doing anything with the strings. Apparently locale initialization is somewhere deep inside QApplication constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the system uses a locale with the KOI8-R encoding? Qt uses the default locale's encoding to access the files, so if it's for example something that uses UTF-8, it won't be able to open a file with name in KOI8-R.

If the locale is different, you should be able to create a custom encoding function (e.g. using [`QTextCodec`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html)) to override this and set `QFile` to use it using [`QFile::setEncodingFunction()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html#setEncodingFunction).

Comment: The locale is definitely KOI8-R. I'm actually porting the code from qt3 to qt4, and in the qt3 version it works just fine with fromLocal8Bit, I've just checked.